# Error type 3: Activity Class {...} does not exist

Tags: android, android-manifest

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.m.e"
      android:versionCode="5"
      android:versionName="3.0">

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name="com.m.e"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.m.e"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.first"
                   />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    .....

</application>

</manifest>
```

**Error :**

```
 Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.m.e/.Splash }
 Error type 3
 Error: Activity class {com.m.e/com.m.e.Splash} does not exist.
```

---

***Note:*** `.Splash` *does* exist.

Comment: Clean and rebuild, there is no problem here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: GO to edit configurations(from the project name dropdown)... over there in general tab under that installations options, in that change deploy from nothing to default apk

Comment: Happened to me after studio upgrade to 4.2 and the accompanying Gradle upgrade to 6.x. That's usually when the most obscure errors come up. Clean and rebuild, as Sniclolas suggested, fixed it.

Comment: @PrinceMidha you are my prince man thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In `build.gradle`, the line:

```
 apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

needs changed to:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: How did apply plugin: 'android-library' even appear in your build.gradle??

Comment: For me I had to replace apply plugin: 'android' (which I was warned is now deprecated), with apply plugin: 'com.android.application' and the error disappeared, it seemed to fail out of nowhere though which is interesting

Comment: Wow, this fixed it for me, and I'm on Android Studio 0.8.6 - weird bug  given the depreciation warning.

Comment: i could not even imagine this solution.

Comment: In my project , there's already com.android.application, but still the issue comes in

Comment: @zulkarnain If apply plugin: 'com.android.application' is already there and still there is issue, just Clean Project and run again. Worked for me.

Comment: @saurabh. Tried that as well with no success

Answer (score 27):

This is how i fixed it. go to **Gradle > Tasks > Install > UninstallAll**

[image]

Comment: I tried everything. But this one worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ShohelRana glad this helps you

Answer (score 25):

I had the same error after renaming/refactoring. What I did was add the `applicationId` property attribute to my build.gradle file, and set its value to the application package. Like this:

```
android{
    defaultConfig{
        applicationId "com.example.mypackage"
    }
}
```

Comment: Refactoring the applicationId to something else and resting it to the original id worked for me!

Answer (score 21):

Although it's a question posted years ago, I would like to share my solution.

Open Run->Edit Configuration, check if "Deploy default APK" is chosen in the package panel. "Deploy default APK" should be chosen.

The problem occurs to me because I choose "Do not deploy anything" earlier for some reason and I forget to undo the chosen.

Comment: That's the only thing that helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks mate, this helped me too!

Comment: I think this is the actual answer

Comment: its was the answear for me

Answer (score 16):

```
adb uninstall <your package name>
```

This is what worked for me. Though the app didn't even appeared as installed app but the uninstall command fixed the problem. 
My theory: Probably some data was left uncleared after a previous uninstall which is causing the next installation to be not fully complete.

Comment: only this helped me after half day of struggle. thanx

Answer (score 11):

Yes I know there's already an accepted answer for this but its not working (or may no longer working). Currently at **Android 8.0 Oreo** version, there's is a chance that your app may be uninstalled on your device "But not for all user". So the next time you debug your App with your device this error happens.

```
Error: Activity class "class path here" does not exist
Error type 3
```

Heres how you fix it which absolutely works (searched for it for 2 days trust me)

1. If you can still see your App under **Settings > App > Select your app** and go to option on its Toolbar and select "**Uninstall For All User**"
2. If your app is not on the App list, **generate/build an APK**, in my case (Android Studio 3.0.1) you can go to **Build > Build Apk**. Install it manually on your device. **Then do Step 1**.

There ! Your app is all cleaned app and perfectly uninstalled. You can now debug it with development environment.

**For further research :** I believe **Samsung Pass app** has something to do with this error. Even after Uninstall. My project is still on their list.

Happy Codings
Cheers !

Comment: This answer deserves a *hero* award ... just unbelievable.

Comment: @vortek glad it helps you.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.5, where is settings?? I have on top AndroidStudio, File, Edit.... etc. thanks for help

Comment: i solved issue from go over project files and be sure project name is the same:: these files are; andorid/app/build.gradle>>android>defaultConfig >applicationId name... android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml package name... android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml package name.....MainActivity.java package name...android/settings.gradle rootProject.name ...android/app/BUCK android_build_config and android_resource package name...

Comment: You are a genius, this app was installed in "work mode" in android 10 so this was causing this whole mess. I truly owe you. Thanks pal

Comment: glad it helps @FranciscoMolina. cheers mate.

Answer (score 6):

Go to your device settings. Select App option, select that particular app from the list, On top right corner, select Menu Bar option and select **Remove for all users**. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I got this error on Android O (Google Pixel C).I think i will get on other devices also.

I tried to install (from AndroidStudio) to any device  it was fine, but not on Android O. On Android o I was getting same error (as given below).

The root cause. I have two users on that device (user1, user2).
When I uninstall the app from user1 (the app is still there in user2).
When I try to reinstall the app on user1 it returns the error.Same case in user2.
To resolve the issue if I uninstall the app from both the users and re-install it works.

From command link if we use "adb install -r example.apk" it works, but  AndroidStudio is not doing uninstall and reinstall (if you have two users in the device).

So in my case its was because of more than one user issue. All my other device (other than Android O) are single user, that is the reason, it was working on other devices, except on Pixel C (with two users).
So watch out for multi user device.

```
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /home/user/Project/AndroidStudioProjects/MyAddress/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.arris.myaddress
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.address/com.example.address.MainActivity1" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.address/com.example.address.MainActivity1" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.address/.MainActivity1 }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.address/com.example.address.MainActivity1} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue with me. I wonder if it's possible to disable a guest user without having to root the device.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced same problem, problem is occurred when I am uninstalling the app and same time I given build.Then in the studio it is given the above error.so I tried every option, but those are not worked for me.So I checked in the **settings -> apps --> selected my application** and I seen the application is in disabled state, so it is not installing (giving error).I uninstalled the application and tried build then it works fine.

Comment: I had the same issue on LG 5 (Android 7) and this answer resolved it! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I tried all of the suggestions above, but only that solved my problem;

1. Change package name irrelevant one and sync gradle.
2. Change package name to really you want, sync and run.

Answer (score 3):

I recently just encountered this error.
I fixed it by completely uninstalling the application on my device, and then re-running.

To offer some context, this was caused by using setComponentSetting()

Comment: Well, after cleaning project, invalidate caches / reestart, delete build folder folders, sync project with gradle files, uninstall Android Studio, install again and update it, I found this sugestion that worked for me... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you manually changed the package name, if the `manifest.xml` is ok, then you need to change

> apply plugin: 'android'

to

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this happens once you rename the project's root directory.

1. Delete the .idea folder of your project.
2. Reopen Android Studio and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Your error states that it is looking for `com.codealchemist.clashmma.splash`. Most Java classes start with an uppercase letter - make sure your class name matches exactly.

Comment: @Binghammer - I've updated my answer. You sure your java class is called `splash` and not `Splash`?

Comment: All my classes do start with uppercase. But for some reason I didn't do it with my splash class. So my class name is lowercase.

Comment: I very much doubt you'd need to do that much. I'd really, really double check that your package name and class match exactly and that `splash` is extending `Activity` (or one of its subtypes).

Comment: Your comment is deleted. Is the question closed ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a devices like my LG Stylus 3 Android 7.0, in which when you press and move app from desktop to the trash, app does not removed from device. See [my accepted answer on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249317/753575) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it's an eclipse issue, so the normal scenarios might work with you. Clean the project and rebuild the work space, open the manifest and check if there is any error, recheck the class name mentioned in the log, clean again and again, restart eclipse , open and clean.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a library module with an example Activity that was specified in the Manifest.

taking out the example activity from the manifest in the library project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the activity was the fix in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue that I couldn't find a solution after searching and trying fixes from here and there. The only thing worked for me is creating a new project, copying all the codes in the old activities and pasting them to the new created activities (similar names but different package). It worked very good. I tried before changing the package name but it didn't work. It might work for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried all mentioned here and they didn't fix my problem. The problem was not in Android Studio but in device instead. 
And after I resetted my Android device to factory settings (as described here https://support.google.com/android-one/answer/6088915?hl=en) the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are building hidden version. That’s intended behavior for hidden app.

If you want to build regular version, you need to change Build Variant in Android Studio **Build > Select Build Variant**, change it to regular.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by restarting my test device and restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your applicationId in the **build.gradle**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by re-installing a previous production version on my Android phone (using the Play store), `flutter run` would run normally after that.

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the solutions worked. Turned out my issue was that I had a guest profile on my Android phone, in that guest profile I had my app installed and forgot about it. On my main profile (which I use all the time) installing the app kept failing with exit code 3.

The solution was to switch to that other guest profile and uninstall the app from there. Or Settings > Apps > Your app > 3 dots menu > Uninstall for all users (If you have more than 1 guest profile, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

In build.gradle,

change

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

If your build.gradle already has `apply plugin: android-library` then try to clean your project.