# Cocos2d js application errors on android

Tags: android, android-activity, cocos2d-js

Hi I am building an android application using cocos 2d js.
I have followed correctly all the installation procedures.
The app compiles correctly..
But when I run using     cocos run -p android i get these errors.

`1.) pkg: /data/local/tmp/CocoDemo-debug.apk
    Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE]

2.) Starting: Intent { cmp=demo.myg/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity }
    Error type 3
    Error: Activity class {demo.myg/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity} does    not exist.
`

The AppActivity class is present in its location.

The app works fine on web.

Any help how to fix this would be greatful.
Thanks.

Comment: Which instructions did you follow?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670607/error-type-3-activity-class-does-not-exist