# Error while launching the app

Tags: java, android

My app is playing crazy. When I run the app it installs it on the device but won't run it. Here is the log:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.callrecorderpro/com.callrecorder.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.callrecorderpro/com.callrecorder.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.callrecorderpro/com.callrecorder.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.callrecorderpro/com.callrecorder.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

I have the MainActivity class and it is declared in the Manifest, I can run the app after is installed manually.

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670607/error-type-3-activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: Google "Error type 3 Error"

Comment: Do you know the reason of this problem?I have been developing apps for 5years and this is the first time i see this.

Comment: In the manifest did you declare the full name or just `MainActivity`

Comment: There is no problem in the manifest ,as i sad I'm not a newbie.There is no problem at all ,I'm working on the project for like 15days ,and this happened today.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings -> Applications -> Click on your app and delete it.

After that if your app marks as "didn't installed" click on it -> click on settings button at the top right and chose "remove for all users".

If it's your case, error will disappear.