# How can I launch an android application using adb?

Tags: android, command-line, adb, launch

my AndroidManifest.xml file have

```
<intent-filter>...</intent-filter>
```

But when I write down adb shell am start -n com.xxx.applicationname/.MainActivity

it logs

Error type:3

Error: Activity class does not exist

Edit my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.applicationname"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Can u post your gradle file?

Comment: I added it @Raghavendra

Comment: Not an exact solution but It might help you please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670607/error-type-3-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me

Comment: post your actual `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Check the application's path to call the activiy in your android manifest file.
For example,when you open your application by touching your phone screen, then in the logcat there would be a hint like this.
[image]

Then find the details in the android manifest file [image]

in this example, the link is the name of activity "android:name=Setting$WifiDisplaySettingsActivity"

So the command for this case is:

```
adb shell am start -n 'com.android.settings/.Settings\$WifiDisplaySettingsActivity'
```

NOTE: the apostrophe marks '  ' and the backSlash \ are very important. You SHOULD NOT miss it.