# Changed package name doesn't work properly

Tags: android, build, refactoring, adb

After I have been developing for quite some time m android application, I decided to change the package name. What I did was:

1. renamed the package tag in manifest

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   package="la.lala.lalala">
   ```
2. refactored the packages in the project treeview in AS
3. An successfully built the project. Now when I am trying to run in on my device I get this error

   ```
   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=
   [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
   cmp=**old.app.package_name**/**new.app.package_name**.controllers.ui.SplashActivity }
   Error type 3
   Error: Activity class    
   {**old.app.package_name**/**new.app.package_name**.controllers.ui.SplashActivity} does not exist.
   ```

In case you didn't understand the problem is that instead of running

```
new.app.package_name.controllers.ui.SplashActivity
```

it is trying to run

```
old.app.package_name/new.app.package_name.controllers.ui.SplashActivity
```

I cannot understand why since I did refactored it properly. I have also tried to restart and invalidate caches but this didn't work either.

Comment: can you share the snapshot of your project's folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it after some googling and some tinkering with it. Thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670607/error-type-3-activity-class-does-not-exist), I checked my build.gradle files. Found out that i was importing

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

which was deprecated, replaced it with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

and it worked correctly :)